# Child reactive form input scrollIntoView with focus

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I try to show the focused input in the screen. I want to put the input field above the keyboard of the phone. What I do now is I edit my height based on the focus and set it back with the blur (not inmportant). In this height I want to put the input visible so it's not hidding under the mobile keyboard. If the input is already inside the height it will do nothing.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="form" [ngStyle]="{'height': elmtHeight}">
   <div class="inner-add-edit" (scroll)="scroll($event)">
   <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div formArrayName="array" [ngStyle]="{'padding-bottom': paddingHeight}">
      <div *ngFor="let item of form.controls.array.controls; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
      <span *ngIf="item.value.datatype === '8'">
        <input type="checkbox" id={{item.value.fieldID}} formControlName="view" class="form-control, input" (focus)="scrollTo(item.value.fieldID, $event)"/>
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="item.value.datatype === '1'">
         <input type="number" id={{item.value.fieldID}} formControlName="view" class="form-control, input" (focus)="scrollTo(item.value.fieldID, $event)" />
      </span>
```

Based on the datatype I show different fields but the most import is the `(focus)="scrollTo(item.value.fieldID, $event)"`
This will call:

```
private scrollTo(_index: any, _event: any) {
        if (window.screen.width === 360) { // phone
            let heigth = _event.srcElement.offsetTop;
            if (this.scrollHeight !== undefined) { // height of the scroll
                heigth = _event.srcElement.offsetTop - this.scrollHeight;
            }
            this.elmtHeight = `250px`;
            this.paddingHeight = `200px`; // padding to let the items scroll up
            if (heigth > 250) {
                let elm = document.getElementById(_index);
                //let scroll = _event.srcElement.offsetTop - (250 + (heigth - _event.srcElement.offsetTop));
                //elm.scrollTo(0, scroll);
                elm.scrollIntoView();
```

Later I tried adding a container id and calculate the offset. But this not show the bottom inputs.

```
let heightElmt = document.getElementById(_id).offsetTop;
let elm = document.getElementById('container');
let newHeight = _index * 22;
elm.scrollTop = newHeight;
```

I'm really stuck on this hope to get some help here.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want to do this, just so that the mobile keyboard won't hide your input field? I'm pretty sure, that the mobile browsers will take care of that.

Comment: I thought so to but it doesn't :( I use chrome for android or firefox but both not working.